# Как найти значения переменной F для каждого значения I?

Tags: delphi

```
FUNCTION f1(a,b,c,x:INTEGER):INTEGER;
BEGIN
   f1:=a*sqr(x)+b*x+c;
END;

PROCEDURE TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
VAR
I, J, C, B, S, F:INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR I:=1 TO 5 DO
        BEGIN
            S:=0;
            FOR J:=1 TO I DO
                 S:=S+F1(1,1,0,J);
            C:=0;
            FOR J:=1 TO I DO
                 C:=C+F1(0,2,3,J);
            F:=0;
            F:=4+S-C
       END;
END;
```

Comment: @Кирил Александрович, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Что за тупизм?

Answer (score 1):

хм... ну если вас просто интересует значение переменной в какой-то момент времени, то указываем брейк поинты (точки останова), запускаем дебаггер, заносим переменную в Watch List, берем попкорн, и наблюдаем изменения.

Можно выводить значение переменной на экран после каждого прохода цикла:

```
ShowMessage('Значение моей переменной: ' + IntToStr(F));
```

или я вопрос не понял?

PS. если у вас из-за неработоспособности алгоритма не получается найти F, то скажите, что у вас просчитывается, и что вы хотите получить.